# How to limit google Maps using latlngbounds and still get user location?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have created an android activity that will take the user location and put a marker on it. My problem is where do I put these codes,

```
    float minZoomPreference = 10.0f;
    float maxZoomPreference = 25;
    mMap.setMinZoomPreference(minZoomPreference);
    mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(maxZoomPreference);
    LatLngBounds Bataan = new LatLngBounds(new 
    LatLng(14.385137,120.277853),new LatLng(14.874146,120.592793));

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(Bataan,0));
    mMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(Bataan);
```

Originally, it is located inside the onMapReady class but the location finder doesn't work, so I removed the code above and the location finder worked just fine.

My problem now is where should i put the code in order for me to limit that map view and the locate the device at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out a way to do it, I just put the code inside my Permission check if Statement

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

//some code
    float minZoomPreference = 10.0f;
    float maxZoomPreference = 25;
    mMap.setMinZoomPreference(minZoomPreference);
    mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(maxZoomPreference);
    LatLngBounds Bataan = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(14.385137,120.277853),new LatLng(14.874146,120.592793));

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(Bataan,0));
    mMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(Bataan);

}
```